# Sentry api authentication issue

Tags: rest, api, authentication, sentry

I am trying to get all the issues with respect to a project by exposing the sentry api hosted on a private server but getting below response even after using basic auth.

{
  "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}

And after generating api key, getting invalid key.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should add this header:

```
header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN'}
```

to your request.